# Howto fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.comma' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pip

I'm trying to import selenium my first time into my new Python project. But when I run the program it does not work and shows the following message below.

I checked if python and selenium is installed correctly. I even tried to reinstall it but still, the same message shows up. I might have made a stupid mistake somewhere as I'm just starting off with Python and Selenium. Does anyone have a solution?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.comma.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

This is the output:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
RESTART: C:\Users\Henryk\Documents\Selenium sample 
project\SeleniumSampleProject.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Henryk\Documents\Selenium sample 
project\SeleniumSampleProject.py", line 2, in <module>
from selenium.webdriver.comma.keys import Keys
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.comma'
>>>
```

Comment: python -m pip install -U selenium

Comment: @Jakub there is no module named `selenium.webdriver.comma` but you are trying to import from it.  fix your import

Answer (score 2):

Try to common:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: This should nail the OP